Why does the lattice need to be even?
I'm studying root systems and lattices in the context of Lie algebra. In Prof. Kac's notes (https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_16_Notes.pdf) it states that if $Q$ is an even (in particular integral) lattice of a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ then the set $\Delta=\{x\in V |(x,x)=2 \}$ is a root system (theorem 16.5) (if $\Delta$ contains a base of $V$).
However, as far as I can see, the theorem does not use in any point the fact that $Q$ is even ( $(x,x)\in 2\mathbb{Z}$ for any $x\in Q$) - just that $Q$ is integral ($(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}, x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$) - since the set $\Delta$ already has the condition that $(x,x)=2$ and it is the one that is used. Am I missing something? Or is the even condition sparing?

I think you are right, the proof works the same as long as the lattice is integral. There also seems to be a missing step in the last sentence, "In the last case", $\alpha=\beta$, "hence $q=0$" etc. --- Note that this construction does not and cannot give all possible root systems, because by definitions all roots in the ones thus constructed have the same length, which is the case only in types ADE.
